# Adding multiple concatenate separators in ADF Dataflow

Tags: sql, concatenation, azure-data-factory, dataflow

This may be a relatively simple question.

I have a data flow that transforms data and loads it into a given destination table.
One of the mappings that I am using in the dataflow is "Derived Columns". Which I am using to concatenate different columns with a space in between them.

See attached below. This is working well so far. However, I want to add another column to concatenate but with a "_" separator. Hence my result which is "123 ABC XYZ" should be "123 ABC XYZ_LMN" . Is it possible to add 2 separators in one expression? Please help. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try nested concatws:

```
concatws('-',concatws(' ',col1,col2,col3,col4,col5),col6)
```